# mkdirs() doesn't work on Gingerbread?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to create a folder that contains a subfolder inside. I wrote this code

```
File myFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath().toString()
                         + File.separator+"Folder/SubFolder"+File.separator);
myFolder.mkdirs();

Log.d("test", "creating the folders");

if (myFolder.exists()) {
    Log.d("test", "folder created");
} else {
    Log.d("test", "there is an error");
}
```

In my logcat I see the folder created and there is an error.
Obviously, I've added the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

permission. Where is the problem?

Comment: We don't know; what's the error?

Comment: Can you add the LogCat prints?

Comment: How can you see "folder created" and "there is en error" ? They're part of the same if/else statement. If you see one, you can't see the other.

Comment: the error is that the folders are not created.

Comment: zouzou, it's possible! see well the code. if myFolder exist write in log "folder created" else echo "there is an error" the "creating the folders" is outside of the if/else statement...

Comment: @GiovanniMariotti yes but you said that you saw **folder created and there is an error** which are both parts of the same if/else statements. So you can't see both at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try removing the File.separator from the file path

```
File myFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath().toString()+File.separator+"Folder/SubFolder");
```

then check if the path exists, if not create the folders.

```
if(!myFolder.exists())
myFolder.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code.

```
File myFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath().toString()
                         + File.separator + "Folder/SubFolder")
```